# Alternatives to Peskin QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

I am following peskin QFT book. I don't find the material convincing. Makes QFT seem like a fairytale from a mathematical standpoint.

Are there more convincing texts, or is the mathematics poorly understood?

Comment: "General principles of quantum field theory", by Bogolubov, Anatoly A. Logunov, A.I. Oksak, I. Todorov

Comment: Weinberg-I is pure gold

Comment: Weinberg I is still a bunch of handwaving mathematics.

Comment: If you want a convincing argument for QFT, there is absolutely nothing better than Weinberg Volume 1. P&S takes the following approach - "Lets just quantize fields for fun. Oh look, this leads us to relativistic particles". Weinberg's approach is this - "We know quantum mechanics is correct. We would now like to add in (special) relativity to this so let us do this. Oh look, this leads us to quantum field theory."

Comment: Schwartz seems good too